# Translating Linux command prompt to windows PowerShell prompt

Tags: linux, windows, powershell

Quick background: I previously used a remote Linux server for a project. Here I was able to pull up the Linux command window in the directory where files from another program were located, and enter a command such as `lspp c= example_file.cfile -nographics`. LSPP in this case is short for LS PrePost - through this command I was able to call LSPP in the background and have it reference the given *.cfile which contains various commands to be executed, such as depositing a given *.csv file with results, its name, etc.

I recently managed to install LSPP for windows locally, and am now trying to essentially translate the functionality of the command I executed in Linux, to Windows. I should add that I have no experience with CMD or Windows PowerShell...

The first thing I tried was to use `cd C:\....` to set the directory to where the *.cfile is located and then enter the same `lspp c= example_file.cfile -nographics` from Linux, however, the response was that "lspp" was either spelled wrong or could not be found.

Next I tried setting the directory to the LSPP program folder, and using `start LS-PrePost-4.7-x64` to at least start the program, but this didn't work either.

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction here - thank you!

Comment: Are you able to run the following (replace PATH with the path to the lspp.exe)?
`Start-Process -FilePath 'PATH\lspp.exe' -ArgumentList 'c= example_file.cfile -nographics'`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I managed to execute the command by setting the `cd` to the current working directory where the *.cfile was saved, and then including the path to the *.exe file as you suggested.